# How to use salt with md5 technique

Tags: php, hash, md5, salt

I have coded md5 technique to store the password in hash but I want to implement it with salt.

here is my register form php with md5 function which is working perfectly.

```
<?php
require("common.php");
if (! empty ( $_POST )) {
    if (empty ( $_POST ['username'] )) {
        die ( "Please enter a username." );
    }
    if (empty ( $_POST ['password'] )) {
        die ( "Please enter a password." );
    }
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM User WHERE username = :username";
    $query_params = array (
            ':username' => $_POST ['username'] 
    );
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare ( $query );
        $result = $stmt->execute ( $query_params );
    } catch ( PDOException $ex ) {
        die ( "Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage () );
    }
    $row = $stmt->fetch ();
    if ($row) {
        die ( "This user name is already registered" );
    }
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO User (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
    $query_params = array (
            ':username' => $_POST ['username'],
            ':password' => $password 
    );
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare ( $query );
        $result = $stmt->execute ( $query_params );
    } catch ( PDOException $ex ) {
        die ( "Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage () );
    }
    header ( "Location: login.php" );
    die ( "Redirecting to login.php" );
}
?>
```

Comment: **Do not use md5 for storing passwords**.

Comment: I just want to know to compare it with sha1

Comment: Sha1 is also obsolete. Don't do that. Use `password_hash()`.

Comment: You really shouldn't use MD5 password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: You shouldn't create your own user and password handling. Try to use a ready-to-go off-the-shelf solution. I would recommend [JBoss Keycloak](http://keycloak.org/) that is based on OAuth 2. There is also a [PHP integration](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use MD5 or SHA1 for hashing (even with a salt) as they are [proven to be insecure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure).

> Using salted md5 for passwords is a bad idea. Not because of MD5's cryptographic weaknesses, but because it's fast. This means that an attacker can try billions of candidate passwords per second on a single GPU.

PHP now provides a simple way to use the far more secure bcrypt hash through the [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, which not only generates a strong hash, but generates a random salt as well

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Md5 is considered insecure and is no more used, You can use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) which uses salt by default to generate strong password hashing. It's easier to use just couple of lines and it's done. Remember do not use your own salt with `password_hash` salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. now it is preferred to use the salt that is generated by default.

Answer (score 0):

**Md5** is the old method for storing passwords.Please have a look at the below links for Hashing password using **salt**

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

http://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/